# jQuery `$("> li", this)` selector syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am found `$("> li", this)` selector in jQuery plugin, that is working same as `find()` function?

**what is difference between both `selectors`**

`$("> li", this)` and `$(this).find('> li')`
both are working same for me, can you please explain the difference between both `selectors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer would be to look in the API

**[jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)**

> context
>
> Type: Element or jQuery
>
> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

In some cases it actually uses `find` internally so they are essentially the same thing written with 2 different syntaxes

Comment: i thought so, only syntax different, i compared with `children()` function but not same, it;s working same as `find()` function, thanks for your answer